# Slow .net application: ZipIOLocalFileBlock.Save on call stack

Tags: .net, windbg

After a few hours of operation my .net application slows down. I took a memory dump and tried to analyze it. What makes me suspicious is that I see several threads having a similar call stack with ZIP in it. I'm not aware of zipping anything... Does anybody know when this happens?

```
 121  Id: 748.2b88 Suspend: 0 Teb: 000007ff`ffda2000 Unfrozen
Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00000000`34bde228 00000000`77ad9e9e user32!ZwUserGetMessage+0xa
00000000`34bde230 000007fe`f83217c7 user32!GetMessageW+0x34
00000000`34bde260 000007fe`ea0e31f8 clr!DoNDirectCall__PatchGetThreadCall+0x7b
00000000`34bde300 000007fe`ea0bcdc0 WindowsBase_ni!?MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen@@20051M1M120N1M08120N <PERF> (WindowsBase_ni+0x1431f8)
00000000`34bde3e0 000007fe`ea0bb483 WindowsBase_ni!?MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOFileItemStream.Write@@2003011N050808+0x68
00000000`34bde4a0 000007ff`00adb96f WindowsBase_ni!?MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOLocalFileBlock.Save@@200001+0x6f
00000000`34bde580 000007fe`f7343008 0x000007ff`00adb96f
00000000`34bde6c0 000007fe`f8358034 mscorlib_ni+0x383008
00000000`34bde780 000007fe`f8358149 clr!CallDescrWorker+0x84
00000000`34bde7d0 000007fe`f83581c5 clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0xa9
00000000`34bde850 000007fe`f83e24ee clr!MethodDesc::CallDescr+0x2a1
00000000`34bdea90 000007fe`f83e2315 clr!ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanupHelper+0x152
00000000`34bded40 000007fe`f73316f1 clr!ReflectionInvocation::ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup+0x1a5
00000000`34bdef10 000007fe`f733163b mscorlib_ni+0x3716f1
00000000`34bdef70 000007fe`f7a6849d mscorlib_ni+0x37163b
00000000`34bdefc0 000007fe`f8358034 mscorlib_ni+0xaa849d
00000000`34bdf010 000007fe`f8358149 clr!CallDescrWorker+0x84
00000000`34bdf060 000007fe`f83581c5 clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0xa9
00000000`34bdf0e0 000007fe`f8358678 clr!MethodDesc::CallDescr+0x2a1
00000000`34bdf320 000007fe`f852d754 clr!MethodDesc::CallTargetWorker+0x44
00000000`34bdf360 000007fe`f83d2fa6 clr!ThreadNative::KickOffThread_Worker+0x148
00000000`34bdf680 000007fe`f83d2f2f clr!SString::AbstractScratchBuffer::AbstractScratchBuffer+0x5a
00000000`34bdf6c0 000007fe`f83d2e9c clr!SString::Equals+0x190
00000000`34bdf7c0 000007fe`f83d2fff clr!CNonVirtualThunk::SetNonVirtualThunks+0xfd
00000000`34bdf860 000007fe`f852d5a4 clr!ThreadpoolMgr::TimerThreadStart+0x9f
00000000`34bdf8c0 000007fe`f84d2ea6 clr!ThreadNative::KickOffThread+0xc0
00000000`34bdf9a0 00000000`779b652d clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x7d
00000000`34bdfd60 00000000`77bec541 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
00000000`34bdfd90 00000000`00000000 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d


0:121> !clrstack
OS Thread Id: 0x2b88 (121)
Child SP         IP               Call Site
0000000034bde338 0000000077ad9e6a [NDirectMethodFrameStandalone: 0000000034bde338] MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.IntGetMessageW(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef, System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef, Int32, Int32)
0000000034bde300 000007feea0e31f8 DomainBoundILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef, System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef, Int32, Int32)
0000000034bde3e0 000007feea0bcdc0 System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.GetMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef, IntPtr, Int32, Int32)
0000000034bde4a0 000007feea0bb483 System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
0000000034bde580 000007ff00adb96f MyApplication(System.Object)
0000000034bde6c0 000007fef7343008 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object)
0000000034bdede8 000007fef8358034 [HelperMethodFrame_PROTECTOBJ: 0000000034bdede8] System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode, CleanupCode, System.Object)
0000000034bdef10 000007fef73316f1 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
0000000034bdef70 000007fef733163b System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
0000000034bdefc0 000007fef7a6849d System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart(System.Object)
0000000034bdf428 000007fef8358034 [GCFrame: 0000000034bdf428] 
0000000034bdf810 000007fef8358034 [DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame: 0000000034bdf810]
```

Comment: This is a native callstack. Please also supply a managed callstack. You can do this by 1) load sos.dll: .loadby sos clr, 2) !clrstack. Also, if you suspect long-running threads, you should check the !runaway output. (This last command works for both native and managed applications.)

Comment: @Dono: I added the managed callstack. Doesn't tell me anything unusual...